# What SQL query is used when opening a table in SAS Guide via ODBC access

Tags: sql, sas, odbc, enterprise-guide

I have in SAS Enterprise Guide 6.1 a libname assigned to a database through ODBC.

If in Server List panel I select table attached to the libname, and open it with right mouse menu, I get the resulting table which I can browse.

Is is possible to see somehow which SQL query the opening of the table sends to the ODBC interface?

**Addition 1:**

I would like to compare the performance when running a `proc sql` query:

`proc sql;
select *
    from temp.cases (obs=100);
quit;`

And when opening the table with right mouse menu and with `Tools > Options > Data > Performance > Maximum number of rows ...` settings set to the value of `100`.

In order to be able to explain the differences in performance I would need to know which query the opening of the table with right-mouse menu uses. Does is read the full table, and then show 100 lines, or read just 100 lines and then show those 100 lines. There could be a huge difference in performance between these two ways of showing data.

Or, is the only way to find out the query used in opening of the data to look at the log of the server which processed the ODBC query?

**Addition 2:**

The problem I had was caused by the string length of some fields, which became the maximum 32767. With 48 string fields that was 48 * 32767 = 1.5 M per one row! Apparently no strings had an "end-of-record" mark, which caused the huge data traffic between SAS Server and SAS Client.

After the data was reformatted to have only the string length with maximum of 255, one row took only 48 * 255 = 12 k, which make a tremendous difference in the speed, when viewing the data by "Opening" the table in SAS Guide viewer! Similar performance loss was not seen when outputting the same data into "SAS Report".

Comment: I think you're on the right track with checking the database server log where the queries ran.  I can't think of any other way other than reaching out to SAS support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it is possible to see a SQL version of what is happening. Since it is SAS, it is probably using a data step or equivalent to populate the table browsing (like using obs= option on a data step set statement).

However, if you are simply looking to find a proc sql equivalent. The outobs option may work for you.

```
proc sql outobs=10;
create table temp2 as select * from temp;
run;
```

Comment: Actually, I was trying this `outobs`-option in `proc sql`, but found different way of working if trying to open the table from mouse meny.